# laravel filtering routes of registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I created a registration form and I am posting the input to route called postRegistration. I want to protect this route (I am guessing filters can be used here) to ensure that only requests coming from route called signup are processed. Otherwise, I would like to direct to another route, i.e. route index.

Here is the route file I have:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');

/*Registration Routes*/
Route::get('signup', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadRegistration'));
Route::post('postRegistration', array('as' => 'postRegistration', 'uses' => 'MembersController@registration'));
```

How can I do this protection using filters? and what should I include more to make it more secure (filter for CSRF for example?)?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this exactly?

Comment: make sure that when someone writes for example site/postRegistration in the browser url, it detects it is not coming from signup route so it redirects them to registration form.

Comment: They can't do that. With the way you're registering the route, the request will only be processed if the request is using the HTTP verb `POST`. Typing the URL into a browser's URL bar will issue a `GET` request which will result in a 404.

Comment: also a CSRF token will almost make sure that it's a legitimate request.

Comment: aha ok thanks for that clarification. If i check for Request::isMethod('post') before executing any code in registration method, will that be good practice to protect?

Comment: aha ok I will add the token based on hidden field

Answer (score 0):

A CSRF token just does that. It ensures that the values posted come from the URL you want them to come from. Here's how you could do it:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function() {
    Route::post('postRegistration', array('as' => 'postRegistration', 'uses' => 'MembersController@registration'));
});
```

You would also have to update `app/filters.php` to handle the redirection you want:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        //throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: it is throwing Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException  error. Any idea why?

Comment: @spacemonkey Are you trying to access the URL with a `GET` request? (Or anything other than `POST` for that matter) If yes, that's what you'd get.

Comment: I am just typing the siteurl.com/index.php/postRegistration in the address bar and executing.

Comment: I am guessing I would need Route::get and Route::post to handle what I am doing as per the previous comment.correct?

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to access the URL with your browser. A hacker that would do this would not see anything because you haven't defined a GET route there. There is no need to secure it. The CSRF token ensures that *POST* requests come from the correct form. To fake a POST request you need to use a browser extension.